# Jquery colorbox problem

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Here is some code:

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js")"></script> 
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.colorbox.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js")"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/colorbox.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

       <div id="large-image">
        <a  href='http://some-image'  class = 'color cloud-zoom'  id='zoom1' rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:10">
            <img  src="http://some-image" />
        </a>
        <a  href='http://some-image2'  class = 'color cloud-zoom'  id='zoom1' rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:10">
            <img  src="http://some-image2" />
        </a>
      </div>
```

As you may already have noticed i use in the same anchor both cloud- zoom and colorbox.
Cloud-zoom works just fine but colorbox does not because of the cloud-zoom plugin.

For instance if i remove `cloud-zoom` from the class of `<a>` this code works fine

```
$('a.color').colorbox({ width: "75%", height: "85%"});
```

So due to the cloud-zoom plugin the above line does not work.
I also tried:

```
 $('#large-image').click(function () {
    jQuery("a.color").colorbox({ width: "75%", height: "85%" });
     });
```

but neither this does not work..

Any ideas??

Comment: Just an observation - you probably don't want colorbox and colorbox-min in there, right? Just one or the other?

Comment: I think the problem is that the cloud zoom code prevents the click action which is what colorbox expects. I don't see anything to tie into any click event in the cloud zoom plugin, so I think you'll have to dive into the code and customize the cloud zoom plugin to get it to work the way you want.

Comment: wel maybe that would work. But i figured it out! it needed a jQuery("a.color").colorbox({ open:true width: "75%", height: "85%" });

Comment: Glad you got it working! I'd add what you used as an answer and accept it just in case anyone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mouseTrap.bind('click',this,function(event){
     $("#zoom").trigger("click");
});
```

add in zoom.js

```
$('#zoom').colorbox();
```